# Linux clone isn't booting

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, grub

I have used rsync to clone all my disks. Then I created partitions and gave them filesystems (ext2). I installed grub. I have done everything that I can think of or what I was able to find on the internet. The system is still not booting :( . What else can I do?

[image: Boot]

Comment: Do you change /etc/fstab and other relatet files to your raid from your clone? Is in your distrie a device.map in /boot/grub? If yes you change it too.

Comment: I have changed /etc/fstab but i dont know what to do about that raid. And yes i have device.map in /boot/grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mount: could not find filesystem '/ dev / root'`
During the boot process, you will mount the filesystem (ext2 in your case).
The attached image will appear to fail to mount ext2.
You will not be able to run ext2's /sbin/init because you have failed to mount ext2 (`switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory`)
Please debug that part.
If Initramfs is present, you can debug the init script. (example) Does the device node you want to mount exist?)
I do not know your environment exactly. (Desktop PC or embedded board, ..)
In both cases, however, `I think you could not mount the filesystem`.
`First, check the device node when mounting the filesystem.`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Radek Pulkrabek Check the `90th line` in the `The Init Script` entry at `http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/luks-and-initramfs/#gref`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an adjusted /etc/fstab and grub config on the clone.
You can edit it manually or simply use linuxclone, which will make a
bootable system replication with just one command, see:

http://fex.belwue.de/linuxclone.html